# High-end Node.js framework

Tags: php, javascript, node.js

I'm kinda new to Node.js world. But I have tried some Node.js frameworks like Express.js, unfortunetly non of them met my requierements.

Since I'm native in PHP, I was looking for some framework similar to Symfony, CodeIgnitier, CakePHP etc.

Basicly, I'm not looking for low-end framework which allows 'only' routing, support for MVC and it is more or less everything.

What I would like to see in strong framework for web apps is something with support of templating system, easy handling HTML forms, user authentication/autoriyation, sessions, caching, emails, some low-end ORM etc. (mostly features which has high-end PHP frameworks)

I know, that Node.js is kinda new technology, but is there some framework, which is going this way? Do you know some releases? Or some groups (forums), where ppl creating and discussing something like this?

Thank you

Comment: I think the reason that something like this doesn't seem to exist, is that people that are using Node.js are using it because they want to build a fast asynchronous application without all the cruft. Why are you using Node.js if it is not solving the problems you are trying to solve? Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

I would send you to [Flatiron](http://flatironjs.com), because it's a great framework, but I think you're looking for (dare I say it?) [Tower.js](http://towerjs.org/). However, I strongly suggest choosing from the large npm module database the modules that suits your needs the best. Flatiron is great for that, as it consists of a set of modules that each do something specific, and ties those modules together in the `flatiron` module.

Comment: It seems to be that there is no active development for this framework. See Github repo: [Flatiron](https://github.com/flatiron/flatiron). The latest release is v 0.4.2 from Sep 16, 2014.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some of the most used Node.js' full-stack frameworks on the site [nodeframeworks](http://nodeframework.com/). If you like OOP and the dependency injection of Symfony (with services) take a look at [Danf](https://github.com/gnodi/danf) (in constrast, don't expect to have all the features of Symfony in it as for now).

Answer (score 0):

Some of the features you mentioned are actually in express.js. I don't think there are any full featured frameworks in the same way as you have in PHP/Ruby/Python. The good news is that Node.js is Javascript and it's a really simple language. So if you need extra stuff on top of express.js it shouldn't be to hard to do that. Not every developer likes this though but I enjoy writing my own small modules to solve certain problems.